# Chained calls to an object and inheritance in Java

Tags: java, android

When declaring a method for chained calls usually it `returns this` at the end of the method.

So I declare:

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo setTitle(String title){
        ...
        return this;
    }

}
```

And:

```
public class Bar extends Foo{

      /* OTHER STUFF */
}
```

If you call `new Bar().setTitle("Test")` it returns a `Foo`'s reference.

Is possible to declare the method in order to return automatically a `Bar`'s reference **without override the method in Bar** for clarity, brevity and maintainability?

Thanks

Comment: No you can not :) can you specify purpose of doing it ?

Comment: Just for chaining methods declared in Bar without casting the returned values of the methods at Foo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is possible to declare the method in order to return automatically a Bar's reference without override the method in Bar for clarity, brevity and maintainability?

No. You could hook up some weird generics - `Foo<T extends Foo>` or the like - but it wouldn't be very satisfactory.

Basically there's need to be some language support for "this type", where the only valid expressions of that type were `null` and `this`. That doesn't exist, so you're left with overriding:

```
public Bar setTitle(String title) {
    super.setTitle(title);
    return this;
}
```

Or:

```
public Bar setTitle(String title) {
    return (Bar) super.setTitle(title);
}
```

It's just one of those cases where inheritance ends up being a pain :(

Comment: Note that overriding the method to return the subclass type requires Java 5 or newer; earlier versions of the language don't allow [covariant return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).

Comment: @Wyzard It android and its Java 5

Comment: @Wyzard: True, but as AmitD says, this is Android - and Java 5 was released over 8 years ago... hopefully there aren't *too* many people using it.

Answer (score 2):

I did try with generics...

```
public class Foo<T extends Foo> {

    public T setTitle(String title){
        .....
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo<Bar>{

    /* OTHER STUFF */
}
```

Seems to work.

Comment: @Addev: Note that there's *nothing* stopping you from declaring `Baz extends Foo<Bar>` or something similar. Fundamentally Java generics don't give you as much compile-time safety as you'd like here.

Answer (score 1):

I think its actullay returning `Bar` Only. **Just do the type casting to reference the object as `Bar`** as below:

```
    Bar bar = (Bar)(new Bar().setTitle("Foo Title"));
    System.out.println(bar.getTitle());//prints Foo Title
```

Assuming `getTitle()` method present in `Foo` returning the title.

If you add another method e.g. `getBarTitle` in `Bar` class:

```
      public String getBarTitle(){
          return getTitle()+" of Bar";
      }
```

then

```
  System.out.println(bar.getBarTitle());//prints Foo Title of Bar
```

**Explanation:**
When you are calling `setTitle` on `new Bar()`, the method is called on `Bar` Object and `this` is representing `Bar` object not `Foo`, hence it returns `Bar` onject only with class type as `Foo`, which is super class. **In this process, it doesn't change the original class type, which is bar at all,**  hence the type casting should serve the purpose for you.

Comment: @Addev: Just curious, this doesn't work for you? If no, what's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use generics with upper bounds:

```
public class Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
    public T setTitle() {
        ...
        return (T) this;
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To be precide, it does not return a Foo reference, it returns a Bar reference, you can check by using System.out.println(reference.getClass().getName()).

In the same way when you write,

```
List l=new ArrayList();
```

(forget about LIst being an interface, it is beside the point)

`l` is actually a reference to ArrayList even if this information is "hidden", but calling l.someMathod() calls ArrayList methods, not List methods - that's how Object Orientation works!