# Chained calls and inheritance

Tags: kotlin

I have a following class hierarchy

```
open class B {
    fun b() = this
}

open class C : B() {
    fun c() = 0
}
```

and I would like to do something like this:

```
fun test(c: C) {
    c.b().c() // error: c.b() returns B, not C
}
```

I understand why such problem [exists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333127/chained-calls-to-an-object-and-inheritance-in-java), but Kotlin has smart casts, so why compiler can't smart cast `c.b()` to `C` in this situation?

Are there any workarounds [better than the Java ones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333209/190148) in Kotlin to make chained calls work correctly with inheritance?

Comment: here is an interesting discussion on these matters: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/this-type/1421/9

Comment: I think overriding the function to explicitly return a C instead of B, calling super.b() should work. But then you have to always override it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Smart cast is not applicable here, since compiler has no way to understand that `B#b()` returns an instance of `C`.

The fact that the returned `B` instance is a `C` is obvious for us, humans, but only after we see the implementation of the method. Type inference can only work with function signatures, so all it sees is `fun b(): B = ...`

A simple solution for your case would be to make `b()` a generic extension:

```
open class B 

fun <T: B> T.b() = this

open class C : B() {
    fun c() = 0
}
```